# Get a substring from an XML file

Tags: java, html, xml, string, javafx

I'm trying to get the `src="path"` of each image inside each `<img>` tag after a Google image research.

Until now I can look all the HTML code, then I need to transform all the HTML code in String, and in the end get a "substring" from the converted string, that should be the image URL of each image.

I commented-out the part of the code that is not working well. If you try that you get this error:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -75875`

I don't understand why I get this error. What am I doing wrong? I tried several things as parameters in "substring" but anyone is working fine, the parameters that we are now were an attempt to take the entire contents of the tag(IMG).

So, How can I take all the paths, and then save it?

Thanks in advance

```
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        WebView webview = new WebView();
        final WebEngine webengine = webview.getEngine();
        webengine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
                new ChangeListener<State>() {
                    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                            Document doc = webengine.getDocument();
                            try {
                                Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
                                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
                                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
                                transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

                                transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc),
                                        new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "UTF-8")));
//                              StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
//                              transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc),
//                                      new StreamResult((writer)));
//                              String output = writer.getBuffer().toString().replaceAll("\n|\r", "");
//                         System.out.println("Outputvale"+output);
//                         String immagine =output.substring(output.indexOf("<IMG")+1,output.indexOf("/>"));
//                         System.out.println(immagine);
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        webengine.load("https://www.google.it/search?q=casa&biw=1440&bih=765&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI0MvF0O3KAhUCGA8KHZixCzIQ_AUIBygC");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(webview, 800, 800));
        primaryStage.show();
    }





    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're already using a Transformer.  Why not give that Transformer an XSL file that strips out everything except `//img/@src`?

Comment: I don't know how to do that.. Is really hard to get a substring from that "transformer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of parsing the HTML yourself, just use the DOM API. Also note it's probably safer to listen directly to the web engine's `documentProperty()` than assume that the document is fully available whenever the load worker completes.

```
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        WebView webview = new WebView();
        final WebEngine webengine = webview.getEngine();

        webengine.documentProperty().addListener((obs, oldDoc,  newDoc) -> {
            if (newDoc != null) {
                NodeList nodeList = newDoc.getElementsByTagName("img");
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element img = (Element)nodeList.item(i);
                    String src = img.getAttribute("src");
                    System.out.println(src);
                }
            }
        });
        webengine.load("https://www.google.it/search?q=casa&biw=1440&bih=765&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI0MvF0O3KAhUCGA8KHZixCzIQ_AUIBygC");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(webview, 800, 800));
        primaryStage.show();
    }





    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution it works, but (it's my fault I didn't say before) I need to get the paths without clicking on the webview, because the user will not see the webview , just insert  one or more words to search in google.

Comment: I don't understand the comment. That code gets the image urls as soon as the page loads in web view (without any user interaction). I updated with the complete executable example. Are you saying you want to get them without displaying the page?

Comment: Thank you, it was my fault.  So, in this way I don't need the "trasnformer", I also saw that the code from the transformer is not the same of the web page (or better the webengine) , why?

Comment: Again, not quite sure what you mean. Are you comparing the output from your original code to opening the page in a browser and doing "View Source"? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes , you're right. I tried to compare the output from my original code and the one of the web page (with FIrefox using analyze element) , and I saw that many things are different also, the paths.

Comment: The web page is written in JavaScript (which may even be automatically generated on the server, e.g. using GWT). When the page loads, the JavaScript executes, and builds the HTML document "on the fly". There's probably some event handling in the JavaScript too, so the document might change in response to user interaction. So your "View Source" shows you the JavaScript the web browser loaded. `getDocument()` gives you a model of the (current) HTML document that is created by executing the JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

IndexOf() will return you the first-occurence. You try to get a substring that consists from "".

In your case calling

`output.indexOf("/>");`

your "/>" is the first one in the html-document, maybe of your "head-Tag" or something else. That would also explain the negative StringOutOfBoundsException.

You have to parse from the index of "IMG" until the first occurence of "/>". That will be the closing one for your img-tag.